# (DONE) Reopen request for parental leave question

Tags: discussion, reopen-request

[Should parental leave benefits apply to non-parents?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/144868/should-parental-leave-benefits-apply-to-non-parents)

I am assuming it was closed as off topic "because of company policy" or "legal" content, but my understanding is that topics that do include legal or policy questions are allowed if there is some broad expectation of the question being universal, or the legal content being common knowledge. For instance, we have had many questions over the years asking about discrimination, or policies related to accommodation for disabilities. Those questions strike me as similar to this one, in terms of their "policy" or "legal" content.

I have voted to reopen this question and am hoping that others will vote to reopen as well.

Comment: The title of the question is mostly philosophical and was probably a poor choice. That's likely what the "close voters" are objecting to. I changed the title, and voted to reopen.

Comment: Thanks Joe for the edit, and others for the reopen votes.

Answer (score 3):

I think people probably closed it for "tone policing" reasons - although if you read the question without any preconceptions it perhaps isn't quite as ranty as it first appears. The overall core of the question is firmly on-topic.

Rights (or lack thereof) surrounding parental leave certainly touches on legal aspects - but it's bread and butter HR stuff.

And a valid answer would be explaining that there is no direct equivalent for non-parents enshrined in UK employment law and suggesting approaches for negotiate with an employer for unpaid time off.

I've cast my VTRO

Comment: I've thought about editing my answer to include other types of "protected leave" such as FMLA in the US. I think the question does open the door for a broader point, which is that there are many cases where unpaid leave is a protected right besides being a parent.

Answer (score 0):

To me, the question reads as a bit of **complaining** \ *minor rant*.

*Parents of a newly born child can take unpaid time off and I cannot, why not?*

My answer would read like:

> Well, your not a parent of a new born and laws and policies have been
>   written for this scenario due to the time strain on both parents when a new child arrives.

This is a question that is a blend of **legal** and at the company level there are *HR policies* around this -- which puts it as off topic IMO.

Comment: I felt the same initially, but after reading the OP's comments, it seemed like their motives were a little more innocent than that. I guess the reason why I posted this here is that I feel like we routinely allow many questions that are just as "company or legal specific" as this one, and it strikes me that the only reason why people closed this one is because they had a negative reaction to it, and not because it's actually any more off topic than other questions which remain open.

Comment: @dwizum My guess is there are a few parents in our community to that took issue with the *tone* of the question.  :-}

Comment: Understandable! I retyped my answer a few times because - as a parent - I didn't really like the tone at first either. I guess I don't think "I don't like your tone" should result in closing a question. But I also know that lots of people VTC simply because they don't like something, versus voting in a manner that's actually consistent or which follows the site guidelines.

Comment: @dwizum a valid point.  I didn't particularly like the question, but did not feel strongly enough that it was necessary to close, but the community felt otherwise.

Comment: "To me, the question reads as a bit of complaining \ minor rant." - I read it that way as well, but mostly in the title.